Display duplicate points in a chart based on a column entry
I want to plot a chart that duplicates points based on a number in a column on the same row.
In each row I have values, say 100, in a column, and number of instances, say 8, in another column. I want to plot a graph that plots 100, 8 times.
I have date/time on x axis with the values on the y.
The date is in column A, time in column B and is combined on the x-axis. Column C then has the value, 100, and column D has the number of instances, 8. So, the graph I want would plot 100 eight times for the same time and date. There are multiple rows with the same situation which would each need to plot the graph in the same way for each row
Is there an option for doing this natively within excel, or do I need to implement a custom code?
I have seen some coding options in visual basic that will duplicate the rows in the sheet but I'd rather not do this as I only need the duplications for the graph display.
Thought there might be a way to do this in pivot tables or in the Power options but not been able to find a solution.

In each row I have values, say 100, in a column, and number of instances, say 8, in another column. I want to plot a graph that plots 100, 8 times. I have date/time on x axis with the values on the y - what is your date data? How do you intend to map your data in columns to time/date data?  Please share example input data and how you would like it to be plotted

Please do not answer in the comments section but edit you question to include all pertinent details.

Thanks, I have amended the question to contain the extra info

would this helps? would plot 100 eight times for the same time and date.  >> https://peltiertech.com/Excel/Charts/ControlBubbleSizes.html

Hello, thanks for that. this could work ok as an option if we cannot get the bar graph solution working, or potentially combine the two. I'll have a play around. thanks
